# How to pass encrypted ID as route parameter in Laravel Route Model Binding

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, routeparams, route-parameters, route-model-binding

I want to pass encrypted ID as route parameter. Currently, I'm using Route model binding and it returns a 404

Comment: Can you share code what you tried?

Comment: Have you decrypted the id in controller?

Answer (score 2):

### You can create a custom resolver for that modal like

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

/**
 * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  string|null  $field
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
public function resolveRouteBinding($encryptedId, $field = null)
{
    return $this->where('id', Crypt::decryptString ($encryptedId))->firstOrFail();
}
```

in the above code you can get the `encrypted` data as `$encryptedId` you can decrypt and used in query to perform search

---

same thing you can do in `RouteServiceProvider`

```php
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

 
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Route::bind('user', function ($encryptedId) {
        return User::where('id', Crypt::decryptString ($encryptedId))->firstOrFail();
    });
 
    // ...
}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic

Comment: Similar question Found here my be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163085/laravel-route-model-binding-shows-404-when-i-passed-encrypted-id-for-editing/71167773#71167773